# PHP: POST variable to next page error

Tags: php, html, post

I have a simple problem.
**Test.php**

```
<form name ="myForm" method="post" id="back" action="homepage1.php">
   Auth:<select name="category" id="category">
   <option>1234</option>
   <option>4231</option>
   <option selected="selected">

   </option>
   <option></option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" id ="submit" name="submit" value = "submit" >
</form>
```

**homepage1.php**

```
<?php
    $selectedid = $_POST['category'];
    echo $selectedid;
?>
```

> error: Undefined index: category in E:\xampp\htdocs\website\homepage1.php on line 121

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: add a submit button to post the form, if you just redirect or open the homepage1.php withou post you will get this error because as no "category" in the $_POST form. You can see more about [POST and how prevent empty post here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Never call anything submit - it hides the submit event handler from JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Select-box options don't have  any `value` attribute, so add them like below:-

```
<form name ="myForm" method="post" id="back" action="homepage1.php">
   Auth:<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="1234">1234</option><!-- add option value-->
        <option value="4231">4231</option>
   </select>
<input type="submit" id ="submit" name="mysubmit" value = "submit" ><!--change button name to something else -->
</form>
```

2.Change `homepage1.php` code like below:-

```
<?php

//comment these two error reporting lines when code started working fine
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if(!empty($_POST['category'])){
    $selectedid = $_POST['category'];
    echo $selectedid;
}
?>
```

Comment: @ENZOAUDITORE Add `ini_set('display_errors', true);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php to output your apparent syntax or other php errors which is resulting in an otherwise blank result.

Comment: PS: dont use submit for a submit id/name like @mplungjan said: Never call anything submit - it hides the submit event handler from JavaScript

Comment: @ENZOAUDITORE  glad to help you. :):) please read-out the comments added inside code currently

Answer (score 1):

Add a submit button to post the form, if you just redirect or open the homepage1.php without post you will get this error because as no "category" in the $_POST form. You can see more about [POST and how prevent empty post here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php).

Also you need to add values to the options like this:

`<option value="4231">4231</option>`

More complete example:

HTML:

```
 <form name ="myForm" method="post" id="back" action="homepage1.php">
   Auth:
   <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="1234">1234</option>
      <option value="4231">4231</option>
      <option value="45698" selected="selected">45698</option>
      <option value="9874">9874</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value = "Go!" >
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//Check if its a empty post
if(!empty($_POST)){
        $selectedid = $_POST['category'];
        echo $selectedid;
}
```